# Problems with bspwm with multiple displays

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, arch-linux, xorg, window-manager

I am trying to setup bspwn on a multi monitor setup. I have an ultrawide 21:9 (2560x1080) and a standard 16:9 (1920x1080). So far I have gotten it working so that it loads the window manager properly on both screens but the monitors are the wrong way arround.

```
How they look on my desk
##########    ##################
#        #    #                #
#  16:9  #    #     21:9       #
#        #    #                #
##########    ##################

How the monitors are displayed in bspwm
##################    ##########
#                #    #        #
#     21:9       #    #  16:9  #
#                #    #        #
##################    ##########
```

So I tried to fix the position of them by running a xrandr command

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --primary --mode 2560x1080 --rate 75.00
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00 --left-of DP-1
```

Afterwards my first desktop on bspwm always defaults to the 16:9 display when I want it on my 21:9. I think that when I run the xrandr commands the screens switches positions bspwm going of the positions relative to other monitors. Is there some way that I can switch the displayed positions of the monitors without it messing with bspwm?

---

~/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc

```
#! /bin/sh

#
# bspwmrc
#

sxhkd &

bspc monitor DP-1 -n center
bspc monitor HDMI-1 -n left

bspc monitor center -d I II III
bspc monitor left -d IV V VI

bspc config border_width         2
bspc config window_gap          12

bspc config split_ratio          0.50
bspc config borderless_monocle   true
bspc config gapless_monocle      true

bspc rule -a Gimp desktop='^8' state=floating follow=on
bspc rule -a Chromium desktop='^2'
bspc rule -a mplayer2 state=floating
bspc rule -a Kupfer.py focus=on
bspc rule -a Screenkey manage=off
```

~/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc

```
#
# wm independent hotkeys
#

# terminal emulator
super + Return
    urxvt

# program launcher
super + @space
    rofi -show run

# make sxhkd reload its configuration files:
super + Escape
    pkill -USR1 -x sxhkd

#
# bspwm hotkeys
#

# quit/restart bspwm
super + alt + {q,r}
    bspc {quit,wm -r}

# close and kill
super + {_,shift + }w
    bspc node -{c,k}

# alternate between the tiled and monocle layout
super + m
    bspc desktop -l next

# send the newest marked node to the newest preselected node
super + y
    bspc node newest.marked.local -n newest.!automatic.local

# swap the current node and the biggest node
super + g
    bspc node -s biggest

#
# state/flags
#

# set the window state
super + {t,shift + t,s,f}
    bspc node -t {tiled,pseudo_tiled,floating,fullscreen}

# set the node flags
super + ctrl + {m,x,y,z}
    bspc node -g {marked,locked,sticky,private}

#
# focus/swap
#

# focus the node in the given direction
super + {_,shift + }{h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -{f,s} {west,south,north,east}

# focus the node for the given path jump
super + {p,b,comma,period}
    bspc node -f @{parent,brother,first,second}

# focus the next/previous node in the current desktop
super + {_,shift + }c
    bspc node -f {next,prev}.local

# focus the next/previous desktop in the current monitor
super + bracket{left,right}
    bspc desktop -f {prev,next}.local

# focus the last node/desktop
super + {grave,Tab}
    bspc {node,desktop} -f last

# focus the older or newer node in the focus history
super + {o,i}
    bspc wm -h off; \
    bspc node {older,newer} -f; \
    bspc wm -h on

# focus or send to the given desktop
super + {_,shift + }{1-9,0}
    bspc {desktop -f,node -d} '^{1-9,10}'

#
# preselect
#

# preselect the direction
super + ctrl + {h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -p {west,south,north,east}

# preselect the ratio
super + ctrl + {1-9}
    bspc node -o 0.{1-9}

# cancel the preselection for the focused node
super + ctrl + space
    bspc node -p cancel

# cancel the preselection for the focused desktop
super + ctrl + shift + space
    bspc query -N -d | xargs -I id -n 1 bspc node id -p cancel

#
# move/resize
#

# expand a window by moving one of its side outward
super + alt + {h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -z {left -20 0,bottom 0 20,top 0 -20,right 20 0}

# contract a window by moving one of its side inward
super + alt + shift + {h,j,k,l}
    bspc node -z {right -20 0,top 0 20,bottom 0 -20,left 20 0}

# move a floating window
super + {Left,Down,Up,Right}
    bspc node -v {-20 0,0 20,0 -20,20 0}
```

~/.xinitrc

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# .xinitrc
#

# Setup X
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
#xrandr --output DP-1 --auto --output HDMI-1 --auto --left-of DP-1
xrandr --output DP-1 --primary --mode 2560x1080 --rate 75.00
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00 --left-of DP-1

# Launch Window Manager
sxhkd &
exec bspwm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with it for a few hours I tried to use arandr since I might not be doing something correct with xrandr and got the xrandr command that works for me.

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --off --output DP-1 --primary --mode 2560x1080 --pos 1915x0 --rotate normal --output DP-2 --off --output DP-3 --off --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
```

EDIT: Above just moved the monitors so that they were switched around and not lined up properly which I found out when setting up lemon bar.

I just figured out the commands which setup the monitors then swaps them

```
bspc monitor DP-0 -d IV V VI
bspc monitor HDMI-0 -d I II III
bspc monitor DP-0 -s HDMI-0
```